# MySQL data type for a field with only two possible options

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to work out which data type to use for a field in my database that can only be one of two options: 'dual' or 'solo'.

I realise that this is essentially Boolean but I can't use tinyint(1) because the inputs are not numbers.

If anyone could give me an idea of what to use in this situation it would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ENUM`

```
colname ENUM('dual', 'solo')
```

Internally it will be stored as a `TINYINT`, but when storing and retrieving it will use the strings.

Or you could use `TINYINT`. The terms "dual" and "solo" refer to 2 and 1 participants, so you could have

```
participants TINYINT(1)
```

and store `1` for `solo` and `2` for `dual`.

Comment: Perfect thank you! However would it not be `0` for `solo` and `1` for `dual`?